# How do i replace accents (german) in .NET

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, diacritics

I need to replace accents in the string to their english equivalents

for example

ä = ae

ö = oe

Ö = Oe

ü = ue

I know to strip of them from string but i was unaware about replacement.

Please let me know if you have some suggestions. I am coding in C#

Comment: Take a look at the answers mentioning "RemoveDiacritics" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470997/replace-german-characters-umlauts-accents-with-english-equivalents

Answer (score 40):

If you need to use this on larger strings, multiple calls to `Replace()` can get inefficient pretty quickly. You may be better off rebuilding your string character-by-character:

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
  { 'ä', "ae" },
  { 'ö', "oe" },
  { 'ü', "ue" },
  { 'Ä', "Ae" },
  { 'Ö', "Oe" },
  { 'Ü', "Ue" },
  { 'ß', "ss" }
};

var res = germanText.Aggregate(
              new StringBuilder(),
              (sb, c) => map.TryGetValue(c, out var r) ? sb.Append(r) : sb.Append(c)
              ).ToString();
```

Comment: Good solution. I've extended it to handle all of ISO-8859-1: http://codepad.org/dUMpGlgg

Comment: shorter: `res = text.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => map.TryGetValue(c, out string r) ? sb.Append(r) : sb.Append(c)).ToString();` ;)

Comment: Updated! Love the evolution of C# with these nice little shortcuts.

Answer (score 11):

Do just want a mapping of german umlauts to the two-letter (non-umlaut) variant? Here you go; untested, but it handles all german umlauts.

```
String replaceGermanUmlauts( String s ) {
    String t = s;
    t = t.Replace( "ä", "ae" );
    t = t.Replace( "ö", "oe" );
    t = t.Replace( "ü", "ue" );
    t = t.Replace( "Ä", "Ae" );
    t = t.Replace( "Ö", "Oe" );
    t = t.Replace( "Ü", "Ue" );
    t = t.Replace( "ß", "ss" );
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any automatic way to do this, so I believe you'd have to do it manually.

ie.

```
string GermanString = "äö";
GermanString = GermanString.Replace("ä", "ae");
GermanString = GermanString.Replace("ö", "oe");
```

How many characters are there? All vowels, in upper and lower case, so, 10? Shouldn't be too much of a job.

Answer (score 0):

How about using string.Replace:

```
string germanText = "Mötörhead";
string replaced = germanText.Replace("ö", "oe");
```

(okay, not a real German word, but I couldn't resist)

You can chain calls to Replace like this

```
someText.Replace("ö", "oe").Replace("ä", "ae").Replace("ö", "oe")...
```

Comment: It's actually M**o**törhead ;)

Answer (score 0):

This class removes diacritic characters (é, ì, è, etc.) and replaces umlauts and the German "ß" with their equivalents "ae (ä)", "oe (ö)", "ue (ü)" and "ss (ß)".

```
public sealed class UmlautConverter
{
    private Dictionary<char, string> converter = new Dictionary<char, string>()
    {
        {  'ä', "ae" },
        {  'Ä', "AE" },
        {  'ö', "oe" },
        {  'Ö', "OE" },
        {  'ü', "ue" },
        {  'Ü', "UE" },
        {  'ß', "ss" }
    };

    string value = null;
    public UmlautConverter(string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    public string RemoveDiacritics()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        string normalizedString = this.value.Normalize();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, string> item in this.converter)
        {
            string temp = normalizedString;
            normalizedString = temp.Replace(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value);
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
        {
            normalizedString = normalizedString.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
            string c = normalizedString[i].ToString();
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(Convert.ToChar(c)) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public bool HasUmlaut()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, string> item in this.converter)
        {
            if (this.value.Contains(item.Key.ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(new UmlautConverter("Nürnberger Straße").RemoveDiacritics()); // Nuernberger Strasse

        Console.WriteLine(new UmlautConverter("Größenwahn").RemoveDiacritics()); // Groessenwahn
        Console.WriteLine(new UmlautConverter("Übermut").RemoveDiacritics()); // UEbermut
        Console.WriteLine(new UmlautConverter("Università").RemoveDiacritics()); // Universita
        Console.WriteLine(new UmlautConverter("Perché").RemoveDiacritics());// Perche
        Console.WriteLine(new UmlautConverter("être").RemoveDiacritics()); // etre
```

There is a minor bug in the "Übermut" case replacing "Ü" with "UE" instead of Ue". But this can be easily fixed. Enjoy :)