# Replacing Non-ASCII characters

Tags: c#, string, replace, non-ascii-characters

I need to write a helper method to generate a username for a given name-surname couple, such that it should return *"amyfarrah.fowler"* for name = *"Amy Farrah"* and surname = *"Fowler"*.

How can i be sure that my username has only ascii chars if name-surname is something like name = *"ÄLİÇEÜ TÃRIĞ"* surname = *"GRÖßERŞİLT"*. The method should return *"aliceutarig.grobersilt"*. It can be done replacing each non-ascii character with the desired one but I wonder if there is any easier solution.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I need to do this using C#

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it. You can see my update.

Comment: Try to always tag your question with the language you mean. This will make it easier for people to help you. Unfortunately I am not aware of any c# library that can help you achieve what you want and honestly saying I doubt there is one.

Comment: Actually have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470997/replace-german-characters-umlauts-accents-with-english-equivalents) should help you.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to solve most of my non-ascii character issues.