# String.Contains() with ignoring case and culture

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I had found only StringComparison, but that's not working for Contains.
Another necessary thing is ignoring case, and "ä" should equials to "a".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static bool CustomContains(this string source, string toCheck)
{
        CompareInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US").CompareInfo;
        CompareOptions co = CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace;
        return ci.IndexOf(source, toCheck, co) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I had never heard of the CompareInfo class before !

Comment: I was skeptical about this solution but it did handle the i, İ, ı and I characters properly (treated them as same). +1

Answer (score 6):

Internally `string.Contains` use string.IndexOf passing a `StringComparison.Ordinal`.
So I think that you could easily write  a method that use the same implementation of Contains

```
public bool CaseContains(string baseString, string textToSearch, StringComparison comparisonMode)
{
    return (baseString.IndexOf(textToSearch, comparisonMode) != -1);
}
```

and call with

```
if(CaseContains(myString, mySearch, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
  ....
```

an elegant evolution of this approach is to create an extension method

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool CaseContains(this string baseString, string textToSearch, StringComparison comparisonMode)
    {
        return (baseString.IndexOf(textToSearch, comparisonMode) != -1);
    }
}
```

and call with

```
if(myString.CaseContains(mySearch, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
   .....
```

Comment: I believe, this is the most elegant solution. But StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCaseare is not recognizing "ä" as "a".

Answer (score 1):

Thats an [umlaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut) over the a. "ä" is not the same as "a". If you want to change it you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: Also, it's more common to replace `ä` with `ae` and  `ö` with  `oe` and so on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271567/how-do-i-replace-accents-german-in-net If he wants to remove diacritics anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7471047/284240

Comment: // "ä" is not the same as "a".
Usually they are not the same, but i need this for product search, so its better to show more results, i think.