# Replace special characters in text file. Best way to do this?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I've got a text file with lines and special characters. I want to replace those. Is this the best way to do this? I've got the feeling this is not the quickest way.

```
Dim lOpenFile As Long
Dim sFileText As String
Dim sFileName As String

sFileName = "C:\test.txt"


lOpenFile = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As lOpenFile
sFileText = Input(LOF(lOpenFile), lOpenFile)
Close lOpenFile

sFileText = Replace(sFileText, " Ç ", " C ")
sFileText = Replace(sFileText, " ü ", " u ")
sFileText = Replace(sFileText, " é ", " e ")


lOpenFile = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As lOpenFile
Print #lOpenFile, sFileText
Close lOpenFile
```

Also i want to sum up things that has been changed. Anyone who can help me with that?

Comment: Is this really VB.NET or VB6?

Comment: I can tell you how to do it with VB.NET, but, as @TimSchmelter said, this looks like VBScript/VB6.

Comment: At this point i'm using VB6 but also working with .NET. Just not that long. If you could help me with .NET you'll make me very happy.

Comment: @Jack: is the last replace correct? You are replacing `é` with `é`, so with itself

Comment: No, sorry. It should be replaced with a " e ". Edited :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you actually want is to remove all [diacretics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) from a string, so accents or umlauts. Then you could use this method which is also efficient since it's using a `StringBuilder`:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDiacritics(s As String) As String
    Dim normalizedString As String = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
    Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder()

    For Each c As Char In normalizedString
        If CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) <> UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark Then
            stringBuilder.Append(c)
        End If
    Next

    Return stringBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

[ remember to add `Imports System.Text` to the top of your code file ]

But note that it will convert an `ü` to `u`(as desired) which isn't correct. Normally you should "translate" german umlauts in the following way: `ü`=`ue`,`ä`=`ae`, `ö`=`oe`. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271567/how-do-i-replace-accents-german-in-net)

You'd call above method f.e. in this way:

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(sFileName)
Dim newText As String = RemoveDiacritics(text)
File.WriteAllText(sFileName, newText)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for taking your time and answering my question! It almost works. The special characters have been replaced with this icon: �.

Any idea why?

Comment: @Jack: sorry, no idea yet. The loop is just appending chars that are no non-spacing-marks(so those who are identifying them as "special" chars). So it's just omitting chars. Try the overload that let you specify the encoding. You should use the original encoding. Try this: `File.WriteAllText(sFileName, newText, Encoding.Unicode);`

Comment: Works greatt! Thanks Tim!